# Rails update nested attributes in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:-

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items, inverse_of: :order, dependent: :destroy
  after_update :update_qantity
  def update_quantity
   self.order_items.each do |oi|
    if oi.saved_change_to_quantity?
      #some logic
    end
  end

end
```

and

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :order_items
end
```

Now, when I do this from rails console:-

```
ord = Order.first  
ord.order_items.first.update_attributes(quantity: 101)
ord.save!
```

The control does go inside update_quantity method, but saved_change_to_quantity? is false(tested by byebug). How should I update nested attributes, so that control does go inside the if statement.

Comment: Since you are calling  `after_update :update_qantity` so after update order it will go to `update_quantity` action , cant get you ?

Comment: But it should go inside if as well, its not going into if, perhaps I need to update like this:- Order.first.update_attributes(order_item.first.quantity =101), what should be the syntax of this?

Comment: `ord.order_items.first.update_attribute(:quantity, 101)`

Comment: @UmeshMalhotra - FYI you've a typo in there: `after_update :update_qantity`. Not sure if this has made the actual code, but thought it might help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got what I was looking for:-

```
Order.first.update_attributes(order_items_attributes: {id: "you_order_item_id", quantity: 101})
```